# Actionscript - Setting minimum size of a Creative Suite extension

Tags: actionscript, adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to set the minimum size of the window of a creative suite extension. I don't want the user to be able to resize the window to a smaller size than the one I define.

Here is what I've tried to do:

```
var instance:CSXSInterface = CSXSInterface.getInstance();
var extension:Extension = instance.getExtensions([instance.getExtensionId()]).data[0] as Extension;
extension.minHeight = 350;
extension.minWidth = 250;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I've also tried to set it in the mxml:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="250" minHeight="350" currentState="Loading"
            historyManagementEnabled="false" layout="absolute">
```

But it doesn't do the trick either. Does anyone know the solution to this problem? I've seen other extensions doing it, namely the Adobe Kuler extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a setting in the manifest file.

In Extension builder, right click on the project, CS Extension Builder > Bundle Manifest Editor. Under the Extension tab, select User Interface. Minimum width and height are some of the settings that can be defined there, along with the extension icon for instance.